# How can I transform some KML data to Sql Server 2008 using FME?

Tags: kml, sql-server, fme-form, coordinate-system

I've just downloaded FME 14 day trial. I'm trying to see how easy/hard it is to transform some KML data (a simple neighbourhood shape) into my Sql Server 2008 database using FME.

I sorta don't even know where to start .. *blush*.

The closest I got was

1. New Workspace Wizard
2. Source file => KML. (OGCKML)
3. Destination => Sql Server 2008 (MSSQL_SPATIAL) + EPSG:4326

After some other questions which I didn't really understand, it then hit PLAY and it did create a table called `Document` but it had a single field which was NULL. I know my KML has data in it .. cause i've loaded it up into Quantum GIS also ... and that worked.

So - could anyone help me please?

Are there any tutorials I could reference to learn if this product is what we need.

I know there's other ways to do this but I want to keep this post only talking about FME and how to use that to do what we're trying.

SIDE NOTE: Any links to pricing? None of us could find any, also ... :~(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create the table to match the schema you want to load the data to in SQL2008. Then you will need to drag the fields from the Reader to the writer so it knows what attributes to match to what locations.
There are some great samples you can see on [FMEPedia](http://fmepedia.safe.com/) that show you the power of the software and you can do a specific search for [KML there](http://fmepedia.safe.com/knowledgeSearch?k=KML) that will give you some great context specific information.
The cost you need to contact them about; there are a variety of options, with different pricing models but I found the reps (mine is Drew) are great at helping you find the right version.

Comment: Any specific samples you might suggest? Also .. there's absolutely no info about pricing .. so what figures are we talking? hundreds? thousands?

Comment: It is a couple thousand off the top of my head, I don't have easy access to my old POs but I am thinking 2,500 for some reason. There is a version specifically that supports MSSQL2008 spatial versus there more generic version or Smallworld version. As for a specific sample, really any of the basic ones will do it, the OGCKML reader is the base reader you want, then you can write to the MSSQL Spatial writer, the key is the table to write to so you can match the fields.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [**Learning page**](http://www.safe.com/learning/training/training-catalog/) on the Safe Software web site.

There are tutorials for both the basic Desktop product (I recommend doing that first) and then one for Spatial Databases. Those two should get you going in no time.

We (I work at Safe) don't put prices out there because there are so many licensing options (and resellers) and we want to make sure users get the product they need. There are also fixed and floating licenses which complicates matters. To write to SQL Server you'll need a 'database' edition (there are several with different names but basically the same functionality).

I suspect the price will be a little higher than the numbers quoted here which I think would be for the lower-level Professional Edition. But I don't work for the sales team so I can't really be sure. But there's no secret to them; just contact our sales team or your local reseller and they will be happy to give you a price.

Answer (score 3):

Addition info on Licensing - Smallword version is the most costly

**Smallworld Edition**
The most complete FME Desktop edition available, with support for all 250+ formats plus the ability for users to read and load data into Smallworld. Learn more about FME support for Smallworld.

**Oracle Edition**
Load data directly into Oracle Spatial and get support for hundreds of spatial and non-spatial data formats. Learn more about FME support for Oracle Spatial.

**Microsoft SQL Server Edition**
Get data in and out of Microsoft SQL Server more easily. This edition also includes integration components for SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). Learn more about FME support for Microsoft SQL Server and SSIS.

**IBM DB2 Edition**
Load data directly into IBM DB2 databases and get support for hundreds of spatial and non-spatial data formats.

**Esri Edition**
Take advantage of tight integration with Esri formats and the Esri Data Interoperability extension so you can work with the familiar Esri ArcGIS interface. Learn more about FME support for Esri.
Note: ArcGIS needs to be installed for FME to be able to write to File Geodatabase.

**Intergraph Edition**
Get support for hundreds of formats and load data into Intergraph GeoMedia SQL Server Warehouses. Learn more about FME's support for Intergraph.

Source:
http://www.safe.com/fme/fme-technology/fme-desktop/how-to-buy/

Cost depends on the country you are in, number of licenses (node locked or floating) and if FME Server is required.
*(a recent quote was on average $2,500 +taxes per floating license includes 1 year maintenance (service packs and outstanding customer/technical support))*

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this out:

https://github.com/pharylon/kml2sql

Free, open source, and easy to use. FME is like a swiss army knife. It has a lot of features, but if all you want is to upload a KML file to SQL server, all you need is KML2SQL.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE but please note that the asker specifically said "I want to keep this post only talking about FME and how to use that to do what we're trying".